# Rails, how do you access the raw request data at the absolute lowest level?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request, lifecycle, actiondispatch

When is the Rails `request` object available at the earliest time during the request lifecycle?   Essentially, when is the request first available as a request object, and in which object? `ActionDispatch`?

Can you access request parameters from `Tester::Application`? If so, how? If not, what about using the environment? When is that information set?

Comment: You need to clean up and clarify your question a bit.  Are you asking how to get access to all request params during a controller action?  If so, that's as easy as writing `puts request` in a controller action and looking at the rails console.

Comment: This was a bit vague, but essentially, when is the request first available as a request object, in which object? ActionDispatch? etc

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Rack webserver creates the `request` object and then ActionDispatch inherits from it.  So essentially, you'd be able to access the `Rack::Request` or `ActionDispatch::Request` objects within the middleware of the app.

**Rack::Request**

https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/request.rb

**ActionDispatch::Request**

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb

Answer (score 3):

A middleware is probably the best way to access this data. I made a simple gem for setting up a raw HTTP request/response log in Rails using the classes mentioned in the accepted answer.

https://github.com/andrhamm/marcopolo

Comment: Thanks for making this. It's exactly what I needed to scrape out tokens from an api service so that I could hit it with curl.

Comment: @JacobDalton no problem, please let me know how it works out for you or open an issue on the github page for ideas for enhancements