# rails: undefined local variable or method `request' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request

I have a mailer class that wants to get the remote user. I access it my `request.env['REMOTE_USER']` but get `request not defined error`. i thought i were able to use request anywhere?

`undefined local variable or method request` for my mailer

Comment: `i thought i were able to use request anywhere`. Totally wrong. You can only access it in controller, view and helpers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you try loading the remote user in your controller action, and either storing in the db, or redis when you're compiling your mailer

---

**Request**

The problem, as stated by Vimsha, is you're not able to access `request` params outside of front-facing code

According to [Rails, how do you access the raw request data at the absolute lowest level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8422716/rails-how-do-you-access-the-raw-request-data-at-the-absolute-lowest-level), you can access the data directly from the middleware if you're working with a direct request (I.E your mailer is not delayed etc)

---

**Structure**

Further to this, I would also question why you're accessing request-specific data directly from your mailer

The modular (DRY) nature of Rails means you need to be able to re-use as many of the assets as possible, meaning you may wish to use the mailer in a totally unrelated action

I'd personally store the request data in the db (or redis if you only want it temporarily), and access it on demand